# Make it clean vs Get it clean - difference?

Tags: meaning, grammar, differences

I would like to know if there is a difference in the following:

> Get it clean! Make it clean!
>   Get it wet! Make it wet!

And which of the following are suitable:

> Make the baby calm
>   Get the baby calm
>   Shut the baby up

Comment: Note that this question was asked more than six years ago. Asking the poster at this late date for clarification on pain of closure seems rather strange, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Get* is rather more peremptory. It is more likely to be used in situations where there is a difference in power between the person giving the order and the person on the receiving end.

In practice, alternatives to your examples, such as *Clean it* and *Calm the baby down*, are more likely in most situations. But it is impossible to say exactly what might be required without knowing the precise context. It would depend on the relationship between the two people involved and what has gone on previously in the conversation.

Comment: Thank you but from the grammar point of view, all are correct? I am never sure where the object will go (Shut the kids up or Shut up the kids?)

Comment: _Shut up_ is normally used intransitively, so it is unlikely to occur like that. If it did, then it would have to be _Shut the kids up_.

Comment: The difference between 'shut up' asa phrasal verb and as a non-phrasal verb is that it means 'make quiet' as a non-phrasal verb (“Shut the kids up, I can't hear anything!”), but 'lock into [a room]' as a phrasal verb: “Shut up the kids in the basement, and throw away the key!”.

Answer (score 0):

Make this dish clean : wash it up yourself (or : eat it up).
Get this tapestry clean : ask a specialist to obtain the result, but don't try yourself.